# app_data does not load values if facebook website is not using ssl

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook share link which does not work if facebook website is loaded without SSL

if facebook loads without ssl (http://www.facebook.com) the share link does load the value in the app_data facebook signed request object

I am using **app_data** app_data={"vId":"108483"} to redirect user to a specified page using the values from app_data

example: https://www.facebook.com/pages/SDA-20/111111?sk=app_461321240572194&app_data={"vId":"108483"}

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution to this problem.

The problem was that our web server was configured to redirect all http request to https and while during that it was giving the HTTP Error 301 Status.

The administrator changed this and now the application works fine with app_data values.